# Which IBM composer gate realizes the 2x2 single-qubit $-I$ matrix?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, ibm-q-experience

Which IBM Quantum composer gate is used to realize the 2x2 matrix $-I$ acting on a single qubit? And how is it called?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly the matrix you give is only a (-1) global phase factor away from the identity matrix

Comment: Yes, thats true, so is there a gate for that in IBM composer ?

Answer (score 1):

The 2x2 matrix $-I$ represents a gate that performs an identity transformation and applies a global phase $e^{i\pi} = -1$ on a single-qubit state. In the IBM Quantum composer you can use any single-qubit rotation gate with an angle $\theta = 2\pi$ to implement such operation. For example, let's consider the $RX(\theta)$ gate:
$$
RX(2\pi) =
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos{\left(\frac{2\pi}{2}\right)} & -i\sin{\left(\frac{2\pi}{2}\right)} \\
-i\sin{\left(\frac{2\pi}{2}\right)} & \cos{\left(\frac{2\pi}{2}\right)}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Upto my knowledge there is no such special gate  in IBM composer to represent the gate
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
which can also be represented as ($e^{iπ}$)$I$

where $I$ is the identity gate and $e^{iπ}$ is a global phase.

There is no special gate to perform this operation but you can use $Z$ gate which is a phase gate to perform this operation however it works when qubit is in state $\left| 1 \right>$.